# Shaped Recipe with specifically named item?

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to create a crafting recipe with bukkit and I want the recipe to ONLY accept a leather helmet with the name "Better Helmet". right now I have this:

```
public static ItemStack lvl2Head = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_HELMET, 1);
{
    //removed unnessecary information
    lvl2HeadMeta.setDisplayName("Better Helmet 2");
}  
public void lvl1ArmorHead() {
    ShapedRecipe recipe = new ShapedRecipe(lvl2Head);
    recipe.shape("AAA", "ABA", "AAA");
    recipe.setIngredient('A', Material.DIAMOND);
        //want it to check it under here in place of "LEATHER_HELMET"
    recipe.setIngredient('B', Material.LEATHER_HELMET); 
    this.getServer().addRecipe(recipe);
}
```

Is there any way I can accomplish this? I tried putting the name of the new ItemStack in place of `Material.LEATHER_HELMET` but it wants `MaterialData` not an `ItemStack`.

**update**

I'm still able to pull the item out of the crafting table using a regular leather helmet this code created with jojodmo.

Main Class:

```
public static ShapedRecipe lvl1ArmorHeadRecipe() {
    ShapedRecipe recipe = new ShapedRecipe(lvl1Head);
    recipe.shape("AAA", "ABA", "AAA");
    recipe.setIngredient('A', Material.DIAMOND);
    recipe.setIngredient('B', Material.LEATHER_HELMET);
    return recipe;
}
public void lvl1ArmorHead(){
    this.getServer().addRecipe(lvl1ArmorHeadRecipe());
}
```

EventHandler class:

```
@EventHandler
    public void craft(CraftItemEvent e){
        if(e.getInventory() instanceof CraftingInventory){
        CraftingInventory inv = (CraftingInventory) e.getInventory();
        if(inv.getSize() != 4 && e.getRecipe().equals(Main.lvl1ArmorHeadRecipe())){
            org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack helm = inv.getMatrix()[5];
            if(helm.hasItemMeta()){
                if(helm.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals("Better Helmet")){
                    //done.
                } else{
                    e.setCancelled(true);
                }
            } else {
                e.setCancelled(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is for Bukkit 1.7.2

Comment: You should also cancel the event if the item has no metadata.

Comment: @flashdrive2049 Thanks for pointing that out, I added it but it still doesn't seem to fix it :( I don't know what I could be missing.

Comment: Probably too old, but should this be moved to arqade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before, It took me so long to figure out how to do it! The only problem is that the result still shows up if you were to use a regular leather helmet, but it just doesn't let you take the result out of the crafting table.

Here's how I did it:

```
public ShapedRecipie lvl1ArmorHeadRecipie(){
  ShapedRecipe recipe = new ShapedRecipe(lvl2Head);
  recipe.shape("AAA", "ABA", "AAA");
  recipe.setIngredient('A', Material.DIAMOND);
  recipe.setIngredient('B', Material.LEATHER_HELMET);
  return recipie;
}

public void lvl1ArmorHead(){
  this.getServer().addRecipe(lvl1ArmorHeadRecipie());
  //do everything in here normally
}
```

Next, use this. Make sure to make the class that this is in `implement Listener`

```
@EventHandler
public void craft(CraftItemEvent e){
  if(e.getInventory() instanceof CraftingInventory){
    CraftingInventory inv = (CraftingInventory) e.getInventory();
    if(inv.getSize() != 4 && e.getRecipe().equals(lvl1ArmorHelmetRecipe())){
      ItemStack helm = inv.getMatrix()[4];//get the middle item in the bench, which is the helmet
      if(helm.hasItemMeta()){//make sure the helmet has item meta
        if(helm.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals("Better Helmet")){//make sure the helmet's display name is 'Better Helmet'
          //you're done! It works! Do something like tell the player "you have crafted better armor" or something here.
          return;
        }
      }
      //the return; above would have been called if the crafting had succeeded. When it got called, the remainder of this method would not run (this part will not be run if the crafting has succeeded)
      //send the player a message to make it more realistic here. For my wizardry server I use: 'One of thee items used was incorrect, and unbalanced the energy. The death block hath been destroyed'
      e.setCanceled(true);
      e.setResult(new ItemStack(Material.AIR));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I am trying to implement this and I found that in eclipse `ItemStack helm` wants to be `org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack helm`, no idea why, but when I craft the recipe now.. and try to pull it out.. it gives it to me o.O it's not canceling it (i'm crafting it with a plain leather helmet). I mean, everything seems right in code, it all makes logical sense but it doesn't seem to actually cancel the event - I'll update my code above.

Comment: @TonyBilby try printing every line to the console (`System.out.println("text")`), so you can see what happens, underneath `ItemStack helm = inv.getMatrix()[5];`, do something like print what material it is, under `e.setCancelled(true);`, print something like *cancelled*, and so on. After that, try crafting and see what messages are printed, that way, you can see what happens in the code.

Comment: @TonyBilby I just noticed a mistake, `helm = inv.getMatrix()[5];` should have been `helm = inv.getMatrix()[4];`. Also, the event would not cancel if the helmet didn't have ItemMeta! (whoopsies!). I updated the code, it *should* work perfect now!

Comment: Also, you may want to look at this thread I started on bukkit a while back: http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/creating-a-custom-crafting-recipe-with-custom-named-ingredients.225735/

Answer (score 1):

Look up the PrepareItemCraftEvent, I've answered your question on the bukkit forums, look at my post: http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/resource-no-nms-make-custom-crafting-recipes-ingredients-obey-itemmeta-displayname-e-t-c.280482/